# How can Appium start server before tests and stop it after tests using gulp task?

Tags: gulp, appium, webdriver-io

Is it possible to start appium server before tests using gulp task and then execute the tests / suite and stop it using another gulp task.

I have created few tests using webdriver io and now want to execute them without manually starting and stopping the appium server.

There is wdio service for the same [wdio-appium-service](https://github.com/rhysd/wdio-appium-service/) but it is not working on windows, [here](https://github.com/rhysd/wdio-appium-service/issues/2) is the issue.